# How to only rotate the positive numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to rotate the array. it works my code. But I would like to rotate only the `positive` numbers.

how to get it?

here is my try:

```
const ar = [1,2, -8, 3,4,5,-3,-44];

for(let i = 0; i< 3; i++){
  ar.unshift(ar.pop());
}

console.log(ar);
```

I am getting a result as : `[5, -3, -44, 1, 2, -8, 3, 4]`;

But looking for the result as : `[3,4,-8, 5, 1, 2, -3, -44,]` so only the `positive` numbers can be rotated. but still if there is a negative number, that should not be touched.

any help please?

Comment: One can make another array of positive value then rotate it 
k times https://leetcode.com/problems/rotate-array/ after rotation traverse the original array if the value is positive then keep replacing the value from second array if it is negative then skip it to next value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to take only the positives, then slice them and recombine to "rotate", and then map back onto the original array by replacing positive numbers with elements from the rotated array.

```js
const arr = [1, 2, -8, 3, 4, 5, -3, -44];
const positives = arr.filter(num => num >= 0);
// Rotate positives by the desired amount
const rotated = positives.slice(2).concat(positives.slice(0, 2));
const output = arr.map(num => num >= 0 ? rotated.shift() : num);
console.log(output);
```